# Subversion and how can I use it?

Tags: php, svn

I just received my first approval for a Wordpress Plugin.  I'm am looking for just a short, general explanation of how to use Subversion in a Wordpress environment.  Wordpress has already provided infomation on it, and I've already found tons of articles on how to use it, and I've found all types of fancy commands that I can type in, etc.

However, I don't understand whether this needs to be setup on my own computer or on a server. And what command line are they referencing - the command prompt through my Windows installation, or is there another prompt on my server?  Confusing!

Also, I downloaded some source code of Subversion, and I have no idea what to do with it.  Is there a way to access this online?  Supposedly, I have a username and password already, but the link they provide only shows the file structure of Subversion, not an actual login screen.

This would be a great opportunity to provide a short, detailed summary of this Subversion system and earn some rep points!

If my question is not appropriate for this forum, I apologize in advance.

Comment: Haven't used it in a while so I'm not going to give a real answer but some pointers: 1. You don't need the source. 2. If you're on windows, get tortoiseSVN. 3. It's designed to track and sync changes, you can use it just locally to keep track of changes to your code, you can also use it to sync/backup that code to a remote server that can then be used as a source to get that code on other computers.

Comment: OK....and I'm guessing there's some type of command prompt that I use there?

Comment: svn, hg, and git use your existing command prompt.

Comment: meaning the actual c:\ command prompt that I can access locally, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), waster **your** time, **not our**

Comment: Wow....you guys are vicious...haha.  I'll be thinking like 8 times before I post future questions. ha